# elantech touchpad - multi touch is not working for kernel 3.13.0-35-generic

Tags: 14.04, kernel, multi-touch

I recently updated my kernel to 3.13.0-35-generic,after update my elantech touchpad multi touch stopped working

I tried fixing it from here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+index?comments=all

But still its not working,I am using ubuntu 14.04,lenovo z510.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: @jan I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

### Fix the kernel 3.13

You can try the patch attached to the bug in Launchpad. So first, download [the patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz) and:

```
cd /path/to/destination/folder
```

Before to install the patch you may need to install the package `dkms` using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then, install the patch:

```
sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c
```

After it's installed successfully, you need to remove and re-add the module from, and to the kernel:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Finally, to make changes permanent on boot:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

The patch works but disables the physical right-click, so I decided to upgrade the kernel.

### Upgrade to newer kernels (e.g. 3.16)

Trying new kernels is not much difficult. All you need is 3 .deb files from [kernel mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) : two linux-headers and linux-image (both of them from either generic or lowlatency) suitable for your architecture and one linux-headers-*-all; for example 3.16 for a 64-bit system will be:

```
linux-headers-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_amd64.deb     
linux-headers-3.16.0-031600_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_all.deb
linux-image-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_amd64.deb
```

You can install them from Software Center, or by commands:

```
cd /path/to/download/folder
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Then you need to update grub settings:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart the system to see if the kernel works. Be aware that proprietary drivers may have problems with new kernels. In the case of your system failed to boot properly, go to **boot advanced option**, select a working kernel to boot. Then remove the non-working kernel, the same example here:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.16.0-* linux-image-3.16.0-*
```

And update grub again with `sudo update-grub`.

**Edit:** It is safer to install kernel packages from Ubuntu repositories with Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager. There are four files of each version; for example, for the latest build of 3.16:

- linux-headers-3.16.0-28
- linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic
- linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic
- linux-image-extra-3.16.0-28-generic

Comment: its started working,Thanks a lot,Just out of curiosity what was I missing? did patch got updated ?

Comment: @user422543, you only missed `update-initramfs` to prevent changes lost after reboot. Furthermore, the patch can have side effects (i.e. broken physical right-click) so I added the update kernel part. But if you mean my edit on your question, well, you just posted the answer inside the question itself. Sorry! I should leave it to you to do on yourself.

Comment: I just tried first part didn't do the kernel update part and regarding "putting answer inside question" I tried all the steps i posted it didn't work for me before and now I am surprised to see its started working

Comment: I just have one quick question I didn't do `update initramfs` I might lose the changes after update thats fine but you said you might lose rt click that happens because of patch or because of the last cmd update initramfs ?

Comment: @user422543 because of the patch.

Comment: @user422543 without `update-initramfs` I lost changes after every **reboot** and I had to do `rmmod` and `modprobe` again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Do a: `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

The right button then will start working.

Answer (score 1):

On my Acer E15 with ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.16.0-31-generic, I had to set the touchpad to Basic in the BIOS. Else the Elantic touchpad did not work at all. But, it did not work well, no scrolling, etc.. But, after having patched the kernel as described above, it worked fine including right-click.

I have an X-config file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` - though I have not checked whether it matters.

```
Section "InputClass"
           Identifier "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
           MatchProduct "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
           MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
           Driver "synaptics"
           Option "TapButton1" "1"
           Option "TapButton2" "3"
           Option "TapButton3" "2"
           Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
           Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1"
           Option "CoastingSpeed" "10"
           Option "EdgeMotionMinZ" "30"
           Option "EdgeMotionMaxZ" "40"
           Option "EdgeMotionMinSpeed" "100"
           Option "EdgeMotionMaxSpeed" "400"
           Option "FingerLow" "9"
           Option "FingerHigh" "12"
           Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
           Option "ClickPad" "True"
           Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0" 
EndSection
```

Comment: You can use the `<$>` button in the editor toolbar to [format code listings](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue try this..

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`
The right button should work.