# Lenovo G510 Bluetooth and Usb doesn't work properly

Tags: usb, bluetooth, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 14.0.1 on My laptop Lenovo G510.

Processor   4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory  8091MB (797MB used)
Operating System    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Kernel  Linux 3.13.0-35-generic (x86_64)
Compiled    #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014
C Library   Unknown
Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Distribution    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

When I start the system sometimes USB ports works and sometimes doesn't work and also Bluetooth sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work after start or restart system.
Somebody can helpme to solve this problem please?
Thank's a lot.
Maurizio

Comment: Having the same problems on Lenovo G5070. Also my touchpad multitouch doesn't work.

Comment: Off-topic: if you have problems with your touchpad multitouch this thread can help as did for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/519747/elantech-touchpad-multi-touch-is-not-working-for-kernel-3-13-0-35-generic