# touchpad not recognized after updtate to 15.04

Tags: 15.04, touchpad

After I updated my touchpad no longer works.  I have a Toshiba e45t-A4200 Touchscreen laptop.  The touchscreen now works fine, but I lost all functionality with my touchpad except for clicking.  My touchpad is not recognized as a touchpad.  Any help is appreciated.
-Josh

Answer (score 0):

You may try several options. The first suggestion is just to reload the module:

sudo modprobe -r psmouse

sudo modprobe psmouse

This solution was found here: http://tinyurl.com/oekhvpe

Another options (from the same website rubuntu.com - on Russian, sorry):

http://tinyurl.com/qcs5b4r

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.Update: I tried your suggestions with no results.  My touchpad is Elantech.  So I tried this too: http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/ with no results

Comment: What about this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/519747/elantech-touchpad-multi-touch-is-not-working-for-kernel-3-13-0-35-generic

Comment: Did you try modify xorg.conf as it was recommended on rubuntu.com? (http://goo.gl/1sYKeQ)

Comment: I did try modify xorg.conf  The problem occured when I was upgrading from 14.04-14.10  I wanted to get to 15.04 and went through 14.10 to get there.  I tried reinstalling 15.04 directly from a USB drive and the problem is now resolved!!!  Thanks for your help!