# Elan Touchpad not working in 15.10

Tags: touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 and then upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop (Fujitsu U745). My touchpad works in Windows but never worked in both versions of Ubuntu.

It shows up in xinput list command

```
    xinput list
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Logitech Gaming Mouse G502                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Logitech Gaming Mouse G502                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

But in dconf-editor it isn't even listed

[No touchpad option listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcdTf.png)

Looking around the web rather lead me to nowhere without this listed. Also the mousepad doesn't even work on login screen too and I have checked the Fn-F4 mouse lock.

**Update**

The Terminal result from the wordpress

```
    leo@LIFEBOOK-U745:~/Desktop$ sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c
    Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
    Building module:
    cleaning build area....
    make KERNELRELEASE=4.2.0-16-generic -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src psmouse.ko.....(bad exit status: 2)
    ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for psmouse: elantech-x551c not found
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-16-generic (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/make.log for more information.
```

*The log file*

```
    DKMS make.log for psmouse-elantech-x551c for kernel 4.2.0-16-generic (x86_64)
    Mon Oct 26 19:14:42 GMT 2015
    make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/psmouse-base.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/synaptics.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/alps.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/elantech.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/logips2pp.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/lifebook.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/sentelic.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/trackpoint.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/touchkit_ps2.o
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.o
    /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.c: In function ‘cypress_process_packet’:
    /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.c:543:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_assign_slots’
      input_mt_assign_slots(input, slots, pos, n);
      ^
    In file included from /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.c:25:0:
    include/linux/input/mt.h:121:5: note: declared here
     int input_mt_assign_slots(struct input_dev *dev, int *slots,
         ^
    scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.o] Error 1
    Makefile:1567: recipe for target 'psmouse.ko' failed
    make: *** [psmouse.ko] Error 2
    make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
```

Comment: Do you get any output when you run `synclient`?

Comment: Yes I do. It just shows the Parameter Settings

Comment: Do you have a line with `TouchpadOff`?

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/questions/519747/elantech-touchpad-multi-touch-is-not-working-for-kernel-3-13-0-35-generic helps Have you googled for "elantech touchpad linux"?

Comment: Also https://hardc0l2e.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/fix-for-elantech-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I have googled around and I do remember inputting a command to change 'TouchpadOff' status however it threw me an error as its not an option is the dconf-editor as stated. I'll reply if the link you sent works.

Comment: I got an error. It says "Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-16-generic (x86_64)". The log will be in the under "Updates".

Comment: That dkms module is incompatible with kernel 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

ELAN Touchpad?!? Well ...    

  „DesignWare“ Touchpad shows similar issues    
easy to fix mostly

You may try "modprobe i2c_hid_acpi". This Tip comes from the Fujitsu Laptop community. Make it a systemd service if t works.     
  update:   
  currently it's    
    i2c-hid or i2c-hid-acpi  
 watch out for the spelling and what is applicable on your system

Actually my Fujitsu E 5511 Lifebook needs this help only for touchpad.    
 Works fine now.    
 Tested with Ubuntu 22.04beta and 20.04.4LTS.

My older E5510 needed "modprobe i2c_hid" to do anything with input.    
 Make it a systemd service if it works.